# CustomQueryParser not retrieving correct documents?

Tags: solr, opennlp, query-parser

I have designed my CustomQueryParser using OpenNLP to transform the query such that it would only contain terms with POS tags 'JJ', 'NNS' and 'NN'.

Example Query = **This is why all the hewlett packard and test**
Query after CustomerQueryParser = **hewlett packard test**

But somehow when i query from velocity, the documents retrieved are not adhering to the above rule. 
Also the default q.op field is not following the 'AND' specified in the solrconfig.xml file.

I am assuming after the CustomQueryParser, the query undergoes through further transformation using the queryAnalyzer.

Could someone please point out where I might be going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "query from velocity" ? If you designed a dismax-like parser you should be able to specify a `mm` parameter (Minimum Should Match clause) `<str name="mm">100%</str>` in your request handler definition.

Comment: I have mentioned my CustomQueryParser here along with how i have intergrated that with solr -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767593/manipulating-query-using-custom-query-parser-in-solr/49768084#49768084                    I am using velocity UI to type in the query.

Comment: Is there any reason why you haven't implemented this as a tokenizer or filter?

Comment: I had to make use of the OpenNLP POS tagger, I read in another post making use of a CustomQueryParser would be ideal for such a case. Is there a better way to solve this? If yes, could you guide me how to or direct me to a resource that could help me with the same

Comment: If you're only removing parts of the input, I'd think writing it as a [charfilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/charfilterfactories.html) would work - charfilters can change the input before the tokenizer and filters get the text, or you could implement it as a tokenizer, that spits out one large token (`hewlett packard test`) and then split it using the `WordDelimiterGraphFilter`.

Comment: Its not just removing part of input i need to run openNLP to keep just the Nouns and Adjectives.  What exactly am I missing with respect to the CustomQueryParser?